# Find and print only duplicate fields only

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask       Iface
192.168.142.223          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:e7   C                     eth0
192.168.142.254          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:z7   C                     eth0
192.168.142.253          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:w7   C                     eth0
192.168.142.230          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:dc   C                     eth0
192.168.142.249          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:b7   C                     eth0
192.168.142.252          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:d8   C                     eth0
192.168.142.254          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:a1   C                     eth0
_gateway                 ether   00:50:56:f0:dd:44   C                     eth0
```

I've got text file like this, my purpose is to print whose first fields are the same.

E.g.

```
 192.168.142.254          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:z7   C     eth0
 192.168.142.254          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:a1   C     eth0
```

my solutions are like this.

```
 1- cat a |awk '{print $1," ",$3}' |grep $(cat a |awk '{print $1}' |sort |uniq -d) 
 2- cat a |awk '{print $3," ",$1}' |sort -k 2|uniq -f 1 -D
```

so I'm curious about, is there any other ways to do it? (maybe usingonly awk commands) I wanna use only bash commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
grep "^$(awk 'seen[$1]++ == 1 {print $1}' a)\b" a
192.168.142.254          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:z7   C                     eth0
192.168.142.254          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:a1   C                     eth0
```

or

```
grep "^$(awk 'seen[$1]++ == 1 {gsub(/\./,"\\."); print $1}' a)\b" a
```

Comment: You would need to avoid matching `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` when `xxx.xxx.xxx.x` is duplicated in the 1st column.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks.... updated...

Comment: @msp9011 it worked thank you so much

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU grep for `\b`. More importanly it'll fail when the input contains `xxx.xx.xxx.xxx` and `xxx.xxx.xx.xxx` since the grep is doing a regexp comparison and the awk script isn't escaping all the `.` "any character" regexp metachars so grep will output the lines for both of those addresses when looking for either of them.

Comment: Btw the array name `seen[]` is idiomatically used for identifying unique values so you can do something when the first or subsequent occurrences of that value are seen in the input, e.g. `awk 'seen[$1]++'` or `awk '!seen[$1]++'`, not for keeping a count and testing when it has a specific value like `1`. In this context you should name your array `count` or similar so the purpose of the array isn't misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell in every UNIX box with any input:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{cnt[$1]++; next} cnt[$1]>1' file file
192.168.142.254          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:z7   C                     eth0
192.168.142.254          ether   00:50:56:f5:0a:a1   C                     eth0
```